# Show a function is one-to-one and onto

Tags: functions

Consider *f*: ℝ{1} → ℝ{1} given by *f(x)* = x/(x-1)

Show that *f(x)* is one-to-one and onto.

What I have:

If a function is one-to-one then it follows that if *f(a)* = *f(b)* then *a*=b.

If a function is onto then it follows that ∀*y*∈Y, ∃*x*∈X such that *f(x)*=y.

So for one-to-one I need to show that if a/(a-1) = b/(b-1) then a=b. That seems obvious enough, however I end up with ab-a = ab-b, which doesn't mean a = b.

NEED HELP WITH ONTO

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure? $$ab-b=ab-a$$ or $$-b=-a$$ implies immediately that $a=b$!!

Answer (score 2):

Try dividing $a-1$ into $a$, and do the same for the term involving $b$ (long division, synthetic division...). Then you can rewrite your fractions and state that
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{a-1} &= \frac{b}{b-1} \\
\Rightarrow 1+\frac{1}{a-1} &= 1+\frac{1}{b-1} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{a-1} &= \frac{1}{b-1} \\
\Rightarrow a-1 &= b-1 \\
\Rightarrow a &=b.
\end{align*}
$$

For **onto**, solve $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$ for $x$ to see that
$$y=\frac{x}{x-1} \Rightarrow \ldots \Rightarrow x=\frac{y}{y-1}.$$
Hence a typical member $x$ of the domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ is of this form. Now when $f(x)=\frac{x}{x-1}$ is evaluated at a typical member of the domain, we get
$$f(x)=f\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{y-1}}{\dfrac{y}{y-1}-1}=y.$$
Since $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$, $f(x)$ is onto.